# Laravel PHP Conditioning between 2 Time h:iA format

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

I want to condition between 2 h:iA formats but it gives me the wrong results for example.

```
8AM > 5PM = true (Correct)
8PM > 5AM = false (Correct)
12PM > 8PM = true (Correct)
5PM > 5AM = true (Incorrect)
8AM >11AM = false (Incorrect)
```

What I want to achieve is the results below,

```
8AM > 5PM = true
8PM > 5AM = false
12PM > 8PM = true
5PM > 5AM = false
8AM >11AM = true
```

The end goal is when it gives me false I want the 2 time to beb like this

```
January 1, 2022 08:00PM - January 2, 2022 5:00AM (If condition is false)
January 1, 2022 08:00AM - January 1, 2022 5:00PM (If condition is true)
```

But I know how to do this, just want to have a solution about the conditioning since its inconsistent.

Comment: make sure the variable that contain the format in time data type, I think it give wrong result because of the data type recognize as string

Comment: Yeah it should be string, because im gonna use it for import which means the data is gonna come from a datasheet, I think I have a work around on this using strtotime function, will further test and answer the question if it works. Would appreciate still if there is better ways to do it.

Comment: So you only want to compare times? I presume the date is also important.

Comment: I have a seperate column for the date, which I will append after comparing the times.

Comment: @kgcusi Tag my name to notify. Ok, so time comparison will be purely done without considering dates?

Comment: Can you share whatever have you tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Please compare two times in this way:

```
$from = date("H:i:s", strtotime("10:00:00"));
$to = date("H:i:s", strtotime("21:00:00"));

$result = $from > $to;
```

Comment: This is correct but youo dont need the date function only the strtotime function

Comment: Yes, you can write the code like this way. But if you use the date function, then you are explicitly mentioning the format of the date. Nothing else.
But if your purpose serves without using the date function, then no need to use that extra function call.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your code but you can compare the data of date first before format it to what you want. here is the example

```
$start = Carbon::now();
$end = Carbon::now();
if($start > $end){
   $start->format('g:iA');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can compare the two time without date using the strtotime function as it converts to integers so better comparison and conditioning instead of the string itself.

```
strtotime('8:00PM') > strtotime('5:00AM) = false
strtotime('8:00AM') > strtotime('5:00PM) = true
```

Then I can just append the date on the seperate column of the datasheet.

```
$mergedDateTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("$date $time"));
```